# How to override TreeNode.Clone() method?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have my own class `MyTreeNode` derived from `TreeNode`:

```
public class MyTreeNode : System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode
{
    [Localizable(true)]
    public bool Foo { get; set; }
}
```

I try to clone the node:

```
MyTreeNode myTreeNode = new MyTreeNode();
myTreeNode.Foo = foo;
//
//And here is the problem, all fields have been copied to the new node but Foo
//
MyTreeNode newNode = (MyTreeNode)myTreeNode.Clone();
```

In result, `newNode` has empty `Foo` field. How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want `Foo` to be copied as well when calling `Clone()`, you'll need to override the `Clone()` method and add the logic to do so.

All you need to do is add this to your `MyTreeNode` class:

```
public override object Clone()
{
    var obj = (MyTreeNode)base.Clone();
    obj.Foo = this.Foo;
    return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this in your MyTreeNode class

```
public override object Clone()
{
    object objReturn = base.Clone();
    ((MyTreeNode)objReturn).Foo = this.Foo;
    return objReturn;
}
```